# Appendix section titles disappear?

Tags: pdftex, appendices

I am writing an appendix in my paper. But it seems the section titles in the appendix part disappear. I've reviewed a lot of relevant problems but doesn't help.
This is my code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\section{...}

\appendix
\section{A}
fgh
\section{sss}
afh

\end{document}
```

But it shows

[image]

I'm using Overleaf v2 pdfLatex to compile and it did not report any errors. So anyone can help?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem, and remove extra part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `\appendices` instead of `\appendix`.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\section{...}

\appendices
\section{A}
fgh
\section{sss}
afh
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Please see $12.1 in [IEEEtran manual](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~steffan/personal/tmp/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf), for more information.